# Implementing ClickOnce MVC5 page for VSTO add-in

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

I have a VSTO (Visual Studio 2012) Excel (2013) add-in that I'd like to deploy via an web page (also VS 2012, asp.net MVC5). The ClickOnce deployment package is generated using a TFS build and works fine from a file share, both initially and for updates.

I'm stuck on the web deploy aspect. I've tried both cshtml pages and htm pages and the setup.exe download works fine, but running the setup fails because authentication is somehow triggered and the vsto content is not delivered (logon page is returned). The controller containing the action for the cshtml page (ClickOnceSetup) is decorated with [AllowAnonymous], and I've tried IgnoreRoute options without success.

Does anyone have a working recipe for this approach? None of the posts or examples I've found have put all these pieces together.

Update 1 (more info): The deploy from the web page works fine locally with IIS Express - the setup executes from the web page and the .vsto file processes without error. When running the same web application from a dev server, if I click on the link to the setup.exe and download it, I get an error that the .vsto file is not found in the downloads folder. If instead of downloading, I choose to run setup.exe (in IE), then I have the authentication problem, details from the "Installing Office customization" error dialog: 
From: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/ExcelAddIn/ExcelAddInV4.vsto
"Exception reading manifest from http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Account.LogOn: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened"
Exception Type: System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException

Thanks in advance,
Reuven

Answer (score 1):

The [Deploying an Office Solution by Using ClickOnce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772100.aspx) article in MSDN describes all the required steps for creating ClickOnce installers for your Office add-ins. Also you may find the [Troubleshooting Office Solution Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608594.aspx) article helpful.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I've reviewed these doc and they are helpful as an overview, but I haven't seen any specifics that point to the issues I'm having.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work through the issues with this approach:

1. In Visual Studio and the TFS build the publish points to a UNC file share
2. After the build I update the publish path in the generated files (vsto, and manifest) with the web site URL using mage.exe. The vsto files are also signed. For the setup.exe, I set the path using the -url command line option (on the setup.exe itself)
3. I upload these files to the ftp folder that mirror the web site url.

My basic issue was that the deployed files needed to be configured for the eventual web url, but that needed to be a step after the build / deploy in Visual Studio. Once I separated those steps, and set the ClickOnce publish/install location as noted above, in my MVC application linking to the setup.exe in that url worked fine.